# Find matching property name in an object and return its value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an unknown strucutred JSON object which I want to read all of its property and return its value when the condition is match.

```
{
      "tags": ["a", "b", "c"],
      "image": "path/to/thumbnail.png",
      "description": "First level description",
      "name": "First name",
      "another": {
        "abcde": {
          "label": "one two three",
          "description": "Oopsy!"
        },
        "fghijk": {
          "label": "Label ABC :)",
          "description": "Is not a song here bruh!"
        }
      },
      "couldBeEmpty": {},
      "couldBeLast": {
        "someCoolName": {
          "label": "Some label here you know",
          "description": "Another Desc Again",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "someLabelAgain": {
          "label": "Just a label name",
          "description": "Yep another Desc :)",
          "type": "color"
        },
        "someObjLabel": {
          "label": "Another label name",
          "description": "Desc label here too",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "ahCoolThing": {
          "label": "Some label for this too",
          "description": "Desc here is fine too",
          "type": "color"
        },
        "couldBeLastInHere": {
          "label": "label",
          "description": "Desc goes here",
          "type": "color"
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to get all **name**, **label**, and **description** for any given structure of the object then make a new object to be something like this

```
{
  "description": "First level description",
  "name": "First name",
  "abcde/label": "one two three",
  "abcde/description": "Oopsy!"
  "fghijk/label": "Label ABC :)",
  "fghijk/description": "Is not a song here bruh!"
  "someCoolName/label": "Some label here you know",
  "someCoolName/description": "Another Desc Again",
  "someLabelAgain/label": "Just a label name",
  "someLabelAgain/description": "Yep another Desc :)",
  "someObjLabel/label": "Another label name",
  "someObjLabel/description": "Desc label here too",
  "ahCoolThing/label": "Some label for this too",
  "ahCoolThing/description": "Desc here is fine too",
  "couldBeLastInHere/label": "label",
  "couldBeLastInHere/description": "Desc goes here"
}
```

Right now I'm trying to use [Lodash](http://lodash.com) for this, but couldn't find a way to find all the property with the given name except having to loop through everything

Comment: Why not just code the recursive loop yourself?

Comment: I have like 3 for loop because I have an expected version of the object, but not really sure what was the right way to do that, and you just remind me of recursive loop! O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is essentially a custom reduction function (you're trying to reduce an object to some compacted representation of its data).  Here's an implementation that allows you to specify which fields you want to pluck out:

```
function myReduce(o, fields, p, c) {
    // p: path
    // c: context (accumulator)
    if(p===undefined) p = '', c = {};
    for(var prop in o) {
        if(!o.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
        if(fields.indexOf(prop)!=-1) c[p + prop] = o[prop];
        else if(typeof o[prop]==='object') myReduce(o[prop], fields, prop + '/', c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

To get the fields you're interested in, you would call it like this:

```
myReduce(data, ['name', 'label', 'description']);
```

Comment: Simple than what I have for three loop! Thank you so much!!

Comment: You deserved this! My `for in` was three time deeper and didn't thought of doing it like this (I guess it's super late and my brain slow down 100x)